# How to replace nested functions with class call

Tags: python

I need to replace a nested function with a class call. Here is the original code.

```
import numpy as np
from variables_3 import vars

def kinetics(y,t,b1,b2):
    v = vars(*y)
    def dydt(v):
        return [
        (b1 * v.n) + (b2 * v.c1),
        (b1 * v.n) - (v.c1),
        (b1 * v.n) - (v.c2)
        ]
    dydt=dydt(v)
    return dydt
```

In this code, variables3.py contains:

```
class vars:
    def __init__(self, *args):
        (self.n,
    self.c1,
    self.c2)= args
```

I would like my final code to look something like this:

```
import numpy as np
from variables_3 import vars
from equations_3 import eqns

    def kinetics(y,t,b1,b2):
        v = vars(*y)
        dydt=eqns.dydt(v)
        return dydt
```

What could the file equations_3.py possibly look like to do this?

I have tried:

```
from variables_3 import vars

class eqns:
    def dydt(b1,b2,v):
            return [
        (b1 * v.n) + (b2 * v.c1),
        (b1 * v.n) - (v.c1),
        (b1 * v.n) - (v.c2)]
```

But that code does not work. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: You're missing `]` in the last function.

Comment: TypeError: dydt() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'b2' and 'v' @Axium

Comment: Well, you didn't provide all the arguments for `dydt`, how do you expect it to function?

Comment: It works in the first code where the function is just embedded though.

Comment: Because the function was embedded. This time, it doesn't have access to `b1` and `b2`.

Comment: Side Note, you can just replace the `return` statement with `return eqns.dydt(b1, b2, v)` since `dydt` is never used after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When passing `dydt=eqns.dydt(v)` in `def kinetics(y,t,b1,b2):`, make sure to pass `b1` and `b2` in your function call. Your `dydt()` function call should look like this: `dydt=eqns.dydt(b1, b2, v)`

Comment: <3 Thank you so much!